# why entity framework code first open close 4 different database connection for a single INSERT?

Tags: entity-framework

I am inserting a row in table in EF code first scenarios, but while I m checking log, I can see 4 different open/close connection and the related activity.

I think, it's a default behavior of EF.

Could someone tell me more regarding this???

```
var ninja = new Ninja
        {
            Name = "SampsonSan",
            ServedInOniwaban = false,
            DateOfBirth = new DateTime(2008, 1, 28),
            ClanId = 1
        };

        using (var context = new NinjaContext())
        {
            context.Database.Log = Console.WriteLine;

            context.Ninjas.Add(ninja);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
```

**Log**

**1. Opened connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:45 AM +05:30**

```
SELECT Count(*)
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES AS t
WHERE t.TABLE_SCHEMA + '.' + t.TABLE_NAME IN     ('dbo.Clans','dbo.NinjaEquipments','dbo.Ninjas')
OR t.TABLE_NAME = 'EdmMetadata'
```

-- Executing at 10/3/2015 11:18:45 AM +05:30

-- Completed in 12 ms with result: 3
Closed connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:45 AM +05:30

**2. Opened connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:46 AM +05:30**

```
 SELECT
[GroupBy1].[A1] AS [C1]
FROM ( SELECT
    COUNT(1) AS [A1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [GroupBy1]
```

-- p__linq__0: 'DataModel.Migrations.Configuration' (Type = String, Size = 4000)

-- Executing at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30

-- Completed in 34 ms with result: SqlDataReader
Closed connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30

**3. Opened connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30**

```
SELECT TOP (1)
[Project1].[C1] AS [C1],
[Project1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId],
[Project1].[Model] AS [Model],
[Project1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion]
FROM ( SELECT
    [Extent1].[MigrationId] AS [MigrationId],
    [Extent1].[Model] AS [Model],
    [Extent1].[ProductVersion] AS [ProductVersion],
    1 AS [C1]
    FROM [dbo].[__MigrationHistory] AS [Extent1]
    WHERE [Extent1].[ContextKey] = @p__linq__0
)  AS [Project1]
ORDER BY [Project1].[MigrationId] DESC
```

-- p__linq__0: 'DataModel.Migrations.Configuration' (Type = String, Size = 4000)

-- Executing at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30

-- Completed in 25 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Closed connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30

**4. Opened connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30**

Started transaction at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30

```
INSERT [dbo].[Ninjas]([Name], [ServedInOniwaban], [ClanId], [DateOfBirth])
VALUES (@0, @1, @2, @3)
SELECT [Id]
FROM [dbo].[Ninjas]
WHERE @@ROWCOUNT > 0 AND [Id] = scope_identity()
```

-- @0: 'SampsonSan' (Type = String, Size = -1)

-- @1: 'False' (Type = Boolean)

-- @2: '1' (Type = Int32)

-- @3: '1/28/2008 12:00:00 AM' (Type = DateTime2)

-- Executing at 10/3/2015 11:18:47 AM +05:30

-- Completed in 131 ms with result: SqlDataReader

Committed transaction at 10/3/2015 11:18:48 AM +05:30

Closed connection at 10/3/2015 11:18:48 AM +05:30

Comment: Querys 1, 2, and 3 are all one time queries that only happen once per AppDomain to "initialize" entity framework, if you had run the query twice you would have only seen query 4 run the 2nd time.

Comment: ok,that's a good point, thanks